# Subtracting after and before values of each sample for each numeric column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataframe in a similar structure of the example below

```
df <- data.frame(rbind(c("Sample1_x2", 10, 23, 6, 5, "Sample1", "after"),
            c("Sample2_x2", 8, 53, 22, 52, "Sample2", "after"),
            c("Sample1_x1", 12, 2, 44, 15, "Sample1", "before"),
            c("Sample3_x1", 27, 46, 16, 65, "Sample3", "before"),
            c("Sample2_x1", 41, 44, 27, 25, "Sample2", "before"),
            c("Sample3_x2", 5, 38, 9, 29, "Sample3", "after")))
colnames(df) <- c("name", "alpha", "beta", "gamma", "rho", "id", "group")
df <- tibble::column_to_rownames(df, var = "name")
df
           var1 var2 var3 var4      id  group
Sample1_x2   10   23    6    5 Sample1  after
Sample2_x2    8   53   22   52 Sample2  after
Sample1_x1   12    2   44   15 Sample1 before
Sample3_x1   27   46   16   65 Sample3 before
Sample2_x1   41   44   27   25 Sample2 before
Sample3_x2    5   38    9   29 Sample3  after
```

I want to get the change dataframe by calculating 'after - before' for each sample by `id`, for each variable column (they are not numeric, and each numeric column has different name). Desired output is:

```
     id   alpha  beta  gamma    rho       
Sample1      -2    21    -38    -10
Sample2     -33     9     -5     27    
Sample3     -22    -8     -7    -36
```

I was trying to use `dplyr::group_by(id, group)` but could not succeed in `mutate()` part to calculate the difference for each sample. Thank you in advance.

Comment: How does your expected output look like?

Comment: Why do you store numeric columns as character types?

Comment: While preparing data and creating the dataframe, they all were converted into character. I will re-check the steps the correct that issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use this approach in `data.table`

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[order(-group), lapply(.SD, \(s) diff(as.numeric(s))), id, .SDcols=1:4]
```

Output:

```
        id alpha beta gamma rho
1: Sample1    -2   21   -38 -10
2: Sample3   -22   -8    -7 -36
3: Sample2   -33    9    -5  27
```

An equivalent approach in `dplyr` is as follows:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  arrange(desc(group)) %>% 
  reframe(across(-group, ~diff(as.numeric(.x))), .by=id)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is one `dplyr` option:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  readr::type_convert() %>%
  summarise(across(where(is.numeric), ~ .x[group == "after"] - .x[group == "before"]),
            .by = id)

#        id alpha beta gamma rho
# 1 Sample1    -2   21   -38 -10
# 2 Sample2   -33    9    -5  27
# 3 Sample3   -22   -8    -7 -36
```

Answer (score 1):

Update after clarification (removed first answer):

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%  
  group_by(id) %>% 
  arrange(group, .by_group = TRUE) %>%
  type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>% 
  summarise(across(-c(group, name), ~first(.)-last(.))) %>% 
  ungroup()


# dplyr >= 1.1.0

df %>%  
  arrange(group) %>%
  type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>% 
  summarise(across(-c(group, name), ~first(.)-last(.)), .by=id)

# See @langtang's solution who uses reframe very elegantly instead of summarise!

 id      alpha  beta gamma   rho
  <chr>   <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 Sample1    -2    21   -38   -10
2 Sample2   -33     9    -5    27
3 Sample3   -22    -8    -7   -36
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I edited my question to show the table I am looking for. Apologies for that. Best